# KeyError when trying to unpickle list

Tags: python, pickle

I have a file containing a pickled list of lists of floats. I can load the list without problems in the same machine that pickled it, but when I tried it in another one, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
  return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
  dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\x00'
```

The two python versions are 2.7.0 (on the original machine) and 2.7.2 (on the one that tried unpickling the file). I don't think there should be any incompatibility just because of that.

Comment: Can you say more about the two machines?  i.e. are they both the same processor architecture?  Are the "list of lists of floats" native Python lists, or are they subclasses of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think there should be any incompatibility just because of that.

Unless there was some bug in 2.7.0 that was fixed in the recent releases. Check the change notes for them, personally I believe [Issue 7117](http://bugs.python.org/issue7117) is the most likely culprit:

> Issue #7117: On almost all platforms: float-to-string and string-to-float
>     conversions within Python are now correctly rounded.  Places these conversions
>     occur include: str for floats and complex numbers; the float and complex
>     constructors; old-style and new-style numeric formatting; serialization and
>     deserialization of floats and complex numbers using marshal, pickle and json;
>     parsing of float and imaginary literals in Python code; Decimal-to-float
>     conversion.

Comment: Apparently, that was it. It took me a while until the machine with Python 2.7.0 could be upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and tried many things but all in vain. Finally, I used cPickle and the problem was resolved. Just replace 'pickle' with 'cPickle' and every thing works fine. It has exactly same methods and args.

```
import cPickle

cPickle.dump()

cPickle.load()
```

Comment: cPickle really saved my situation...  Following were my other issues and fixes:

Comment: cPickle really saved my situation...  Following was my issue:
Python 3 pickle couldn't be loaded in WebSphere Jython 2.1 version, figured I had to restrict to the lowest protocol=0 while pickling.

Answer (score 0):

With python 2.7.12 could not unpickle json file with list i.e.
*[{"k": 0},{"k": 1}]*

cPickle did not help, json did:

```
import json
json.load(open(file))
```